# Should we use elastic search for business logic?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cassandra, jhipster

I have a jhipster app with Cassandra as the database. Also, along with Cassandra, I'm using elastic search. Currently, I am using it for all the searching and data fetching mechanism. But recently I have read somewhere that we shouldn't use elastic search for business logic. So should I use it for searching purpose only or is it ok to fetch data using elastic search.
Please note I am not using elasandra.
We are storing data in Cassandra as well as in the elastic search for indexing purpose.

Elastic search version:  5.6.3
Cassandra version: 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually slightly misleading, but you still have 2 very good questions here. The main confusion comes from your use of the term "Business Logic" so I want to clarify that slightly first, and then answer your actual question.

First, business logic (a.k.a. domain logic) is the set of rules that determines how your data can be created, stored and/or changed. In your stack, this would be handled by the Spring code. So, no, Elasticsearch should not be handling the actual business logic.

But the actual question you are asking is should Elasticsearch be used for data retrieval as well as searching? Elasticsearch actually makes a great data store (although I strongly suggest using it only as a secondary data store and focus on basic search and fetching). Using Cassandra as your primary data store, and then using Elasticsearch to quickly fetch pieces of the data is a good design practice, so carry on!

Comment: I am currently using cassandra and would like to add elasticsearch for data fetching. Could you briefly explain the correct setup? Cassandra remains the main data storage - how does elastic index the data?

Comment: @AlexTbk Once you have Elasticsearch up and running, you need a way to load the data from Cassandra into the new index. This can be a script or an endpoint of your service. Basically, scan the Cassandra database, convert each document to JSON, and then insert that document into your new Elasticsearch index. You can insert documents one at a time with the Index API, or batched using the Bulk API. Here's how to work with documents: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html

Comment: Thank you. I gave elassandra a go and it seems to integrate pretty neat

Comment: one more question regarding ElasticSearch and Cassandra: actually it feels like there is no longer a need to replicate data in cassandra to serve different queries as one could issue the queries towards the elasticsearch. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexTbk I am personally hesitant to make Elasticsearch my primary data store. It is really not built to be a database, so I like to keep it focused on serving search requests, while I do all my primary data writing to the data store (Cassandra in your case). This way, if I need to pause on adding data to the index, it is still being stored in Cassandra and I can go back later and add what I missed to the index.

Comment: @AlexTbk Plus, Elasticsearch is "Eventually Consistent" which means data is not always immediately available to query on when I add it. Databases are typically much better at that task.

Comment: yeah i understand that, but im thinking not about using elastic as the primary data store. I am thinking about serving most of the data requests from elastic where the data is coming from the underlying cassandra db. In this case its elassandra, which combines elastic and cassandra. cassandra is not really good in paging results, this is where elasic would help a lot. Adding/removing entrys to cassandra are mirrored to elastic. If elastic fails then there will (should?) be no data corruption - one could just rebuild the indexes.

Comment: @AlexTbk Ahh, I see what you are saying. Then yes, you can totally serve the data up from Elasticsearch. In fact, that is what I do and it works out really well. The only caveat I want to mention is that paging a lot of documents (like 10k+) can be hard on Elasticsearch, so keep that in mind when designing your solution.